# Is there a way to handle number inputs instead of string with React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a react context state for my multi form input values:

```
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    sex: "male",
    unitSystem: "metric",
    heightInCm: "173",
    weightInKg: "60",
    dateOfBirth: null,
  });
```

and I am struggling to undestand how I should handle my number inputs, like height and weight. At the moment I have to store them in a string format, because `TextInput` only accepts a string. I find myself having to keep converting string to number for validations.

For example this is my input handler:

```
  const toCm = (foot: string, inches: string) => {
    const footInCm = convert(parseInt(foot)).from("ft").to("cm");
    const inchesToCm = convert(parseInt(inches)).from("in").to("cm");
    const actualCm = footInCm + inchesToCm;
    return actualCm;
  };

  const handleImperialSubmit = () => {
    toCm(foot, inches);
    setFormValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      heightInCm: toCm(foot, inches).toString(),
    }));
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };
```

is there a way to work with actual numbers in react native, because this is very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: No.

The longer answer: Still no, there is no way to have react native's TextInput return numbers to you, partially probably because there's no way to restrict the input to numbers only *that's built into TextInput*. You do have a couple options  that might make your life easier.

1. Because this is all just javascript (or typescript we don't discriminate) you could implement this functionality yourself:

```
const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null)

return (
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={textValue => {
      if(!isNaN(textValue) && !isNaN(parseInt(textValue))) {
        onChangeNumber(parseInt(textValue))
      } else if (textValue === "") {
        onChangeNumber(null)
      }
    }}
    value={number?.toString()}
    keyboardType="numeric"
  />
)
```

You could create a component out of this or wrap the logic into a hook for reuse on all your "numeric inputs". The example above might be a little overkill after setting the keyboard to numeric but from that keyboard you can include a decimal which you may or may not want. The logic can be updated accordingly.

2. Speaking of hooks, there are a plethora of form libraries that you might be interested in that do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Some options include:

- [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik)
- [React Hook Form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form)
- [React Final Form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form)

among others.